# Get Model name in a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there any way to get the name of current model in a partial view?

I want to do something like:

```
@if(Model.Name=="Something"){
....
}
else{
...
}
```

Comment: please try @model.GetType().Name

Comment: Great Thanks a lot. This is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use try something like

```
@model.GetType().Name
```